# JQuery - Values from JSON into split() then update var

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have an JSON array, and 2 of the keys and multiple values, i want to split each value, and if one of the values exist then it will set a var to 1.

```
var heroism = 0;
var stats = 0;
var crit = 0;
var stamina = 0;
var spellPower = 0;
var spellHaste = 0;
var mastery = 0;
var attackPower = 0;
var attackHaste = 0;

var classes = {
    mage: [{
        0: "mage",
        1: 0,
        2: "heroism, crit, spellPower"
    }],
...
};

    $.each(classes, function (key, data) {
        $.each(data, function (index, data) {
            if (data[1] == 1) {
                var i = 0;
                var getBuffs = data[2].split(', ');
                $.each(getBuffs, function (key, data) {

                // update relevant var to 1
                data[i] = 1;
                i++;

            });
            $.each(getBuffs, function (key, data) {
                $.each(data, function (index, data) {
                    console.log('index', data);
                });
            });

        } else if (data[3] == 1) {
            //do something else   
        }
    });
});
```

What it is currently doing is putting each letter as an array object rather than the whole word. I think this part is wrong `data[i] = 1;`

My full code can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Qju8D/1/)

Thanks

Comment: Why is `mage` an array when it contains only one element?

Comment: Im using the array to store the "buffs" the class has in the key 2, and in key 1, states if the class is in the raid group. As for key 0, im using it as the identifier for the object in another part of the code.

Answer (score 0):

It's a very awkwardly designed JSON structure I must say.

The immediate problem here is that

{
        0: "mage",
        1: 0,
        2: "heroism, crit, spellPower"
}

this snippet actually defines an object literal, the correct way to access it is actually using '.', such as data.1, data.2, instead of accessing in the array way with square brackets.

Thus it would make more sense to rename those attribute into things like name, buff etc

Comment: You can access object properties in that object with `data[0]`, `data[1]` and so forth. Using "dot access" isn't "correct" in the sense of being the only way to do it - in a general sense it works only for some property names, whereas the square bracket notation works for all property names.

Comment: I'm pretty new to JSON and JQuery - im learning and get stuck on some areas - particularly arrays - i thought that this could be the best way to store multiple values per class (mage)

Comment: oops this wont allow me post longer comment